# Unable to install MongoDB perl

Tags: perl, mongodb, cygwin, cpan

I've got a new Win7-64bit box at work, replacing an old XP-32bit box.
In both cases I am using Cygwin perl.
Despite having previously installed and used perl MongoDB module on the old box, I haven't yet been able to install it with cpan on the new box.
I have successfully installed other modules (e.g. YAML) on the new box, but MongoDB is failing
on one of its prerequisites Config::AutoConf which fails with:

## Looks like you failed 12 tests of 28.

Is there a known problem with Config::AutoConf on 64-bit?  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

```
# Found AWK as /usr/bin/gawk
# Found SED as /usr/bin/sed
# Found EGREP as /usr/bin/egrep
t/01.checkprog.t .. ok
t/02.compile.t .... 4/?
#   Failed test 'PERL_VERSION_STRING declared'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 40.
t/02.compile.t .... 8/?
#   Failed test 'PERL_API_* declared'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 43.
t/02.compile.t .... 9/?
#   Failed test 'perl_parse() declared'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 48.

#   Failed test 'I32 is valid type'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 53.
t/02.compile.t .... 11/?
#   Failed test '[SAH]V * are valid types'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 56.
t/02.compile.t .... 12/?
#   Failed test 'I32 has size of n/a bytes'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 61.
t/02.compile.t .... 13/?
#   Failed test 'Could determined sizes for I32, SV *, AV, HV *, SV.sv_refcnt'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 63.
t/02.compile.t .... 14/?
#   Failed test 'have struct av.sv_any member'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 70.
t/02.compile.t .... 16/?
#   Failed test 'have struct hv.sv_any and struct STRUCT_SV.sv_any members'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 73.
t/02.compile.t .... 17/?
#   Failed test 'Align of I32'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 78.
t/02.compile.t .... 18/?
#   Failed test 'Align of SV.sv_refcnt'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 80.
t/02.compile.t .... 19/?
#   Failed test 'Could determined sizes for I32, U32, AV, HV *, SV.sv_refcnt'
#   at t/02.compile.t line 82.
# Looks like you failed 12 tests of 28.
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the `Config::AutoConf` tests?

Comment: It sounds like your Cygwin install does not have a C compiler toolchain set up. Can you try running setup-x86_64.exe and see if the `gcc` package is installed?

Comment: I do have a functional gcc, just confirmed it with "hello world" program

Comment: How about the header for libperl? Do you have `perl.h`?

Comment: When I additionally installed g++ then it worked.  If you want to put that into an answer @friedo I will accept it.

Comment: glad you got it working. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config::AutoConf` requires a number of prerequisite compiler toolchain, libraries, and header files to function correctly. On Cygwin, installing the `gcc` and `g++` packages should get you everything you need.